# How to skip the "yellow" VM scripts when debugging in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging Javascript by loading the webpage, pressing F8 in the debugger and then entering a line in the console.

This works well, however there is a whole labyrinth of about a dozen step-into + skip steps, till I can get out of the "yellow" VM pages and into the real code with the white background.

I enabled blackboxing for the VM script in question and the debugger tells me that "This script is blackboxed in debugger", but the behaviour didn't change at all, the dozen or so step-into + skip steps are still needed till I can get out of the "yellow" VM part and into the "white" script part.

How can I skip the yellow part and get directly to the actual command I'm entering in the console?

Update: it seems that Chrome Canary skips the dozen or so steps required on the yellow page and brings you just one step away from the script code.

Comment: Seems odd that it seems it can't tell you any context on where these VM scripts are from.